# calendar.monthrange() function is showing an error

Tags: python

```
import calendar
import string
year = str(input("Year:"))
month = str(input("Month:"))  
t  = (calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1]);
print(t[1]);
```

*input:
Year:2000
Month:2
output:
if not 1 <= month <= 12:
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'*

Comment: ERROR: if not 1 <= month <= 12: TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

Comment: ...why are you passing strings to `monthrange`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `calendar.monthrange(year, month)` function accepts two numbers as inputs. So first you will need to change that. 
Additionally, `t  = (calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1]);` refers to the second element in the array. Hence the variable t is no longer an array. Hence `print(t[1]);` would give you a TypeError.

```
import calendar
import string
year = int(input("Year:"))
month = int(input("Month:"))  
t  = (calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1]);
print(t);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Putting `semicolons` at the ends of Python statements is as useless
2. `calendar.monthrange` get `int` as argument

> ```
> year = int(input("Year:"))
> month = int(input("Month:"))
> ```

3. `calendar.monthrange` returns a `tuple` of int and `t[1]` is wrong

> ```
> t  = calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1]
> print(t)
> ```

or

> ```
> t  = calendar.monthrange(year, month)
> print(t[1])
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Turn the input into an int instead of a string and lose the "[1]" on line 5

```
import calendar
import string
year = int(input("Year:"))
month = int(input("Month:"))  
t  = (calendar.monthrange(year, month));
print(t[1]);
```